# detect input during on-going call sip android senddtmf

Tags: android, asterisk, sip

I need to login on a phone server. I can now successfully dial the phone, however during the on-going call I need to detect the inputs(id) by the user using the custom dialer. I'm not sure how to detect the input using a custom dial-pad.

What am I missing?

Here is my code so far:

```
  SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                // Much of the client's interaction with the SIP Stack will
                // happen via listeners.  Even making an outgoing call, don't
                // forget to set up a listener to set things up once the call is established.
                @Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {  
                    call.startAudio();
                    call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                    call.sendDtmf(digit);
                    //call.toggleMute();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                }

            };
            call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener, 30);
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing reading asterisk book. What exactly you need? Where is asterisk dialplan? What  type of channel used/which dialler?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called DTMF which stands for [**Dual-tone multi-frequency signaling**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling)

I did not get the chance to use [SipAudioCall](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipAudioCall.html) but a quick search indicates that you will need the following method:

- [public void sendDtmf (int code, Message result)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipAudioCall.html#sendDtmf(int,%20android.os.Message))
- [public void sendDtmf (int code)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipAudioCall.html#sendDtmf(int))